# Adding script to autostart

Tags: arch-linux, x11, profile

I have this script:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080
1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-1 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

This is .tele1 file in /home/user

I wish that this script is run with the system, but don't know how...

Comment: It depends on how you start the X Window system, so you should specify your environment (Desktop Environment / Window Manager)

Answer (score 1):

You can't add it to `~/.bashrc`, because you call graphical command, you should write a service for `systemd`. and call before `gdm` , `kdm`, or your `Display manager`.

You can use [Systemd Services](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Services)

Comment: I have XFCE. I don't know good unix systems so if You can tell me where i need paste this code.

Comment: I don't systemd and upstart, you have systemd because you use archlinux, But i show you main solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using XFCE you can do the following to have your script run when you log in:

*excerpt*

> If the command turned out successful all you need to do is open up your “XFCE Settings Manager” and go to “Session and Startup” then click on “Application Autostart” and add the command to your autostart so every-time you boot your displays will adjust.

**Source:** [Setting up Dual Monitors on XFCE Arch Linux](http://ianmarmour.com/2012/01/22/setting-up-dual-monitors-on-xfce-arch-linux/)